# Adding currency in discord.js, stacking cents into a dollar

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, discord.js

So I'm using the discord.js library and MongoDB. And I'm making a basic economy with dollars and cents. So far, I am working on a "!daily" command. So every day, a user can run that command and randomly get money added to their account. The thing is, I don't know how I can stack the cents. For example, if a user has 80 cents in their account, and I add 30 more cents to their account, I want it to be "$1.10" not "0.110".

Daily Command:

```
const chance = require('chance').Chance(); //Chance is an NPM package, it generates numbers by chance. Docs: https://chancejs.com

let money = chance.weighted(['50', '100', '500', '1000'], [.80, .10, .05, .02]);
    var randomMoney = money[Math.floor(Math.random()*money.length)];

    const profileData = await Profiles.findOne({ userID: message.author.id });

    if(!profileData.moneyCount >= 0.00) {
      await Profiles.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          userID: message.author.id,
        },
        {
          $inc: { moneyCount: randomMoney }
        },
      )

      message.reply(`$${randomMoney} has been added to your account!`);
    }
```

Comment: Code would be helpful to understand what's the error with your calculations

Comment: Just Updated It.

Comment: What is the problem here ? It's simple addition tbh, if the current balance is 0.30 and you want to add 0.80 you simple do 0.3 + 0.8 = 1.10 ..

Comment: In your code you can simply do : $inc: { moneyCount: profileData.moneyCount + randomMoney }

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I'm sorry, that completely flew over my head. I don't know what I was thinking. I'm sorry

Comment: That's ok, :) everyone do misstakes